# Convergence of probability of an event within increasing # of samples

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory, infinity, random

**Let's say there is a 10% chance of an event taking place per 100 samples**. If you increase the number of samples to infinity, theoretically the chance of the event occurring would converge 100%. But imagine this:

**If you treat infinity as an infinite amount of sets of 100**, would each of those sets still have only 10% chance of the event taking place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes on both accounts...

If there is a 10% chance of an event taking place per 100 samples, then then the probability of an event taking place is $p = 0.001$ per sample. Then let $X_n$ be the number of events that occurs in a sample of $n$ trials. Clearly,

\begin{equation}
X_n \sim Binomial(n,0.001)$.
\end{equation}

To see the first question, consider:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n = 0) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}0.999^n = 0
\end{equation}

To answer the second question, let $Y_1, Y_2, ... \sim Binomial(100,.001)$

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}P(Y_n > 0) = .001
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you, very clear and logical answer!